# SOLR connection string for ARM template

Tags: solr, arm-template

I am installing Sitecore using the `ARM template` and using SOLR as a search service. Now I have configured SOLR as master/slave model. While installing Sitecore, which connection string should I provide in the ARM template?

As per my understanding, it should be Master, and later on, we need to change the connection string in the CD server.

Can anyone please confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short - I would recommend using `SolrCloud` in a model where you have a load balancing in place (either by the built-in Solr Load Balancing or by an external load balancer that is handling the load between the nodes). This should be the recommended approach for handling the shards optimally.

In that case you must connect to the load balancer url and pass `solrcloud=true` in the connection string.

So your connection string should look like this:

`https://[LOADBALANCER_URL]:[LOAD_BALANCER_PORT]/solr;solrCloud=true`

If you need some inspiration you can refer to [Setting up SolrCloud Documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/walkthrough--setting-up-solrcloud.html).

If you are not having a load-balancing in place (which I wouldn't recommend :)). You should just connect to the `Master` server on all the servers that are doing `writes` and use the slave for all the servers that are doing `reads` as  normal Solr servers, but you are going to lose the primary capabilities of scaling :).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. By default, ARM templates use **Azure Search** if we are not providing the `SolrConnectionString` parameter which is specified in `azuredeploy.parameters.json` file. `SolrConnectionString` is used to identify whether a Solr search provider is to be used for the deployment or not.

Since we only have one parameter for Content Delivery, Content Management, Processing, Reporting Sitecore roles in the ARM template, we can pass the Solr Master connection string and later on can configure the CD servers for using Slave or a more better way is to use a load balancer with multiple slave servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Solr IaaS instance`. In CM, Master URL and if one slave then slave URL in CD, if more than one slave then it should be behind Load Balancer and Load Balancer URL needs to be mentioned in CD.

The CD changes you have to do manually. You can check the article for configuration changes

http://amitkumarmca04.blogspot.com/2019/03/sitecore-error-troubleshooting-sitecore.html